# sort by a desc and b asc - array(key => array(a, b)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
$array = array($team => array('points' => x, 'runs' => y))
```

And I aggregate points and runs with the same team and the result is something like this:

```
[team1] => Array
    (
        [points] => 12
        [runs] => 1
    )

[team2] => Array
    (
        [points] => 11
        [runs] => 3
    )

[team3] => Array
    (
        [points] => 11
        [runs] => 2
    )

[team4] => Array
    (
        [points] => 8
        [runs] => 3
    )
```

And I want to sort it by runs DESC and by points ASC.
to be like:

```
[team4] => Array
    (
        [points] => 8
        [runs] => 3
    )
[team2] => Array
    (
        [points] => 11
        [runs] => 3
    )
[team3] => Array
    (
        [points] => 11
        [runs] => 2
    )
[team1] => Array
    (
        [points] => 12
        [runs] => 1
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) (to keep the keys intact, you can use `usort` otherwise) with a custom compare function:

```
uasort($teamArray, function($first, $second) {
    // first preference to points
    if ($first['points'] < $second['points']) return -1;
    if ($first['points'] > $second['points']) return 1;

    // points are equal, compare runs in descending order
    if ($first['runs'] > $second['runs']) return -1;
    if ($first['runs'] < $second['runs']) return 1;

    // both points and runs are equal
    return 0;
});

print_r($teamArray);
```

Comment: I was trying with usort but I didnt know how to take it :) It is working :)